# How to print the contents of a broadcast variable

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I created a broadcast variable in the pyspark shell and I want to simply inspect whats inside of it.

But, the functions that I'd normally use to print or view an RDD are not available to a broadcast variable.

i.e. `.collect()` and `.take(5)` etc all throw the dreaded `Broadcast object has no property ...` errors.

How do I view the data stored in a broadcast var?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess in Python is similar. I show you an example in Scala.

```
scala> val broadcastVar = sc.broadcast(Array(1, 2, 3))
broadcastVar: org.apache.spark.broadcast.Broadcast[Array[Int]] = Broadcast(0)

scala> broadcastVar.value
res0: Array[Int] = Array(1, 2, 3)
```

if you save the result of broadcastVar.value, you will get a T, in a variable you can print it or whatever using the default toString method of the type T.